# Auto-Refresh UI when data change

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to refresh my UI when data changes. I have a ListView to display Cards that contain my events, and these events are sorted with a datepicker. When I change the date with the datepicker I need to reload the page to display the correct pages.

I try to pass the datepicker data as a parameter of the ListView  to sort the events in the ListView, I also tried to sort the data before ListView is built with a parameter containing the list of sorted data.

Widget of my HomePage class :

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Image.asset('assets/logo2.PNG', fit: BoxFit.contain),
    title: Text(widget.title,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'IndieFlower',fontSize: 30,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    actions: <Widget>[      // Add 3 lines from here...
      new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Color(0xFFf50057)), onPressed: _pushSaved, iconSize: 35,),
    ],                      // ... to here.
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF263238),

  ),
  body: FutureBuilder<List<Event>>(
    future: fetchPosts(http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      //print(convertIntoMap(snapshot.data));
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListViewEvents(posts: sortEvents(snapshot.data), pickerDate: '${dobKey.currentState.dobDate} ' +dobKey.currentState.dobStrMonth +' ${dobKey.currentState.dobYear}')
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Color(0xFFf50057),));
    },
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar  :  BottomAppBar(
    child: Container(height: 100.0,
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    child:
      DatePicker(
          key: dobKey,
          setDate: _setDateOfBirth,
          customItemColor: Color(0xFFf50057),
              customGradient:
                  LinearGradient(begin: Alignment(-0.5, 2.8), colors: [
                Color(0xFFf50057),
                Color(0xFFffcece),
                Color(0xFFf50057),
              ]),
    ),
  ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

This is my map:

```
    List<Event> sortEvents(List<Event> data) {

 List<Event> eventsSelected = new List<Event>();

  for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++){
    if (data[index].date == 
 //callback of datepicker   
'${dobKey.currentState.dobYear}-${dobKey.currentState.month}-
${dobKey.currentState.dobDate}') {
              eventsSelected.add(data[index]);
    }
  }

  return eventsSelected;

 }
```

And this is how I render my cards:

```
  class ListViewEvents extends StatefulWidget {
  ListViewEvents({Key key, this.posts, this.pickerDate}) : super(key: key);

  final posts;
  final pickerDate;

    @override
  _ListViewEventsState createState() => _ListViewEventsState();
}

class _ListViewEventsState extends State<ListViewEvents> with 
SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            if(widget.posts.isEmpty) { 
              return  Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No events for this date'
                ),
   );
            }   
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.posts.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return  Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Title : ${widget.posts[index].title}'
                ),
   );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I actually have a system to display my events's Cards that works but it's not in real-time, I would like to refresh the UI when the data of the datepicker changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setState()` when list data changes.

```
  for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++){
    if (data[index].date == 
 //callback of datepicker   
'${dobKey.currentState.dobYear}-${dobKey.currentState.month}-
${dobKey.currentState.dobDate}') {
              setState(() { eventsSelected.add(data[index]); } ); <--- add it here.
    }
  }
```

Comment: that return 'Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.'

Answer (score 1):

you can use setState() for this problem so setState() call when anything change in the  screen